# Configuring relevance in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

dear Community.

It would be great if somebody can help me.

We have n-types in index, every type has own set of columns(fields).
When I want to search across all index, I need to configure relevance depending on type and type field.

How can I do it?

Thank you for your attention.